# how to use compressed texture in opengl?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to use `.PVR` image for texture purpose.
For this, I used `PVRtextool` and loaded my `pvr` image in drawables-mdpi.
Now, when i use this in my project the app just crashes.

Am I missing some step?
Please guide.

Here is the load texture code where I'm getting problem.  `resource` contains the image in `.pvr` format.

```
static void loadTexture(GL10 gl, Context context, int[] resource)
   {  
       gl.glGenTextures(n, textureIDs, 0);
       BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       opts.inScaled = false;
       for (int face = 0; face < n; face++)
       {

           gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[face]);

           bitmap[face] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            context.getResources(), resource[face],opts); 


           gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
           gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);


           GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap[face], 0);
                  bitmap[face].recycle();
}
]
```

Comment: Have you tried using debugger to determine location of crash?

Comment: YES.Its happen in following line: 
  GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap[face], 0);

Comment: Well and what have you determined? Is bitmap variable initialized? Is face initialized? Does bitmap[face] contains valid value?

Comment: [On using compressed textures in android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#textures).

Comment: I think here lies the problem ,the bitmap[] contains null .....
i donnt not why this ambiguity but the same code goes well for png and jpg images.

Comment: Well, what about showing us some code?

Comment: @stefan The code is added to the question

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` with that format. You have to use the `openRawResource()` function and pass the `InputStream` it returns to the `ETC1Util.loadTexture()` function.

A sample implementation should be at `/sdk/platforms/<version>/samples/CompressedTextureActivity.java`, or an online version is [here.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java//com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.3_r1/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CompressedTextureActivity.javaext)